# Angular2 customize the number of form groups

Tags: angular, radio-button, angular2-forms, angular-reactive-forms

I have a problem with my reactive form. I need a single radio-button group that combines with the added text-inputs. Here the [current preview of my input set](https://picload.org/view/rcprwggr/inputs.png.html)

Following the current code in my template:

```
<div class="form-group row" formArrayName="externCallerIds">
              <div class="col-sm-5">
                <label for="extern-caller-ids" class="col-form-label">{{ 'USERS.extern' | translate }}<br>
                  <a class="btn btn-secondary add-button" id="extern-caller-ids" (click)="addExtCallerId()">Hinzufügen</a>
                </label>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-7">
                <div *ngFor="let item of userForm.controls.externCallerIds.controls; let i = index" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
                  <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon" [formGroup]="userForm">
                      <input formControlName="externCallerId" type="radio" [value]="item.value">
                    </span>
                    <div class="input-group">
                      <input formControlName="{{ i }}" type="text" class="form-control col-12">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group-btn" *ngIf="i > 0">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" (click)="delExtCallerId(i)"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

The main problem is that by adding a new input the radio-button-group generates a new group although every radio-input-value is different and the input-name the same. What can I do to get a single group of radio-buttons?

I tried to implement this part of my project in Plunkr. It doesn't work but the code in the `app.ts` is identical to my script.

Comment: Hi, Can you create plunkr for this? As it will make us understand what actually you want more specifically.

Comment: Hi, I tried to implement this part of my project in Plunk here:
http://plnkr.co/edit/GilKx80fW8ulBQUkGkKH?p=preview
but it doesnt work. But the code in the app.ts is identical to my script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it is not fully clear. I assume you are not getting single select for the radio button list. So here is the thing. Please do it like this.

```
<input formControlName="externCallerId" name="radiogroup" type="radio" 
      [value]="item.value">
```

Let me know if this is what you were looking for or not.

Comment: Hi Ronak, thank you very much. You have fixed my trouble. The single change/problem in your solution is the name of the input. I changed it to "externCallerId" - after that the radio-button-group works for me :))
PS: I didn't know that angular need a name attribute because of the "formControlName" for reactive form inputs.

Comment: Yes it does require `name` for grouping.